# How do I add a variable index in mongolite

Tags: r, mongodb, indexing, mongolite

R version: 3.4.2,
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (4.10.0-37-generic),
Mongo DB version 3.4.10,
Mongolite v1.2.

Based off of [Mongolite manual](https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/query-data.html#indexing), I am trying to add an index based off my data in R. I would like this index to take up the value based on a variable's value in the data.

I have created my Mongo DB, and access it in R using:

```
margo<-mongo(collection="test",db="test1",url="mongodb://localhost", verbose=TRUE)
```

I was able to use the variable name approach to run find queries as per other answers on stackoverflow ([updating an entry in mongolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37631954/r-updating-an-entry-in-mongodb-using-mongolite))

```
margo$find(query=paste0('{"FileName": "',test1$FileName,'"}'))
```

However, I cannot figure out how to add a variable-based index. For example if my variable is `val=1` and I am trying to create an index named "trya", then when I try

```
margo$index(add=paste0('{"trya":"', val,'"}'))
```

I get an error message:

> Error: Unknown index plugin '1'
>   Obviously, if I do

```
margo$index(add=('{"trya": 1}'))
```

this works just fine. Newbie to mongo usage, so my apologies if I am missing something obvious about variable formatting.

Update: I was able to use

```
margo$index(toJSON(list("trya" = val),auto_unbox=TRUE))
```

to add numeric indices (following from [github mongolite report on importing compound indices](https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/issues/82)). If val is a string variable, this does not work  (same error message).

Comment: after your update, are you still having issues?

Comment: The more I think about, I cannot see why/how a string can be an indexer. So in that sense, yes, I don't have any more  issues on that subject. But I am still not sure how to use "add" with a variable indexer. Is that not possible? Is the way I resolved it, the only way around the problem?